# Is there a word describing the feeling when cold water is drank, similar to "spiciness"?

Tags: word-request, adjectives, vocabulary

Weird question, but you see how spicy food can be described by the word “spiciness”? How can one describe the feeling when cold water is drank? Do you know any adjective which describes this best?

Comment: Brain freeze, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The word **coldness** would be the equivalent here, although it may depend on which quality you are trying to describe.

Also, note that “spicy” and “cold” are adjectives, but “spiciness” and “coldness” are nouns.

Comment: Exactly. Although it's only correct based on the parallel structure implied by the question. It's not entirely clear what sensation is being thought of when drinking cold water. (*Refreshing* also comes to mind. As does *cooling*, which is more equivalent in terms of the temperature. But it's also not clear if it's a noun or adjective that's actually being looked for.)

Comment: Isn't the noun 'temperature'?

Comment: @Chaim: In a strictly technical sense, yes, but here we’re talking about the sensation of a cold drink, so I think “coldness” is probably more appropriate. Spiciness has spicy at the top of its spectrum, and coldness has cold at the top of its spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

In Vietnamese, we have the adjective "[buốt](https://vi.wiktionary.org/wiki/bu%E1%BB%91t)", which describes the feeling of numbness caused by pain or cold. I would personally translate this to "numb" or "biting cold", and I hope that's the feeling you're looking for. But if you want to describe the pain in your teeth when you drink cold water, you can just say that your teeth hurt from drinking cold water.